Mermaid 10 + Render + Click
I it possible to attack a global click handler when rendering a Mermaid chart in this manner
I don't want add the click handlers to the markup, I want to add it as a global handler at the time that I initialize


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="flowchart" class="mm"></div>
    <script>
        window.element = document.querySelector('#flowchart');
        window.clickFunction = function(nodeId) {
            alert('Clicked on node ' + nodeId);
        };
    </script>
    <script type="module">
        import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';
        console.log(clickFunction)
        mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad: false, securityLevel: 'loose', click: clickFunction});       
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function () {
        const drawDiagram = async function () {
            const graphDefinition = 'graph TB\na-->b;';
            const { svg, bindFunctions } = await mermaid.render('graphDiv', graphDefinition);
            element.innerHTML = svg;
            // This can also be written as `bindFunctions?.(element);` using the `?` shorthand.
            console.log(bindFunctions)
            if (bindFunctions) {
                bindFunctions(element);
            }
        };

            drawDiagram();

      });
      </script>

  </body>
</html>



